# how to set fans on maximum

Tags: linux, ubuntu-10.04

How can I set my processor fan to 100% in linux?

Comment: Why, are you using your PC for HVAC?

Comment: No, my computer often overheats and fans are not well configured.

Answer (score 5):

You'd be better to just improve your case airflow or get more fans, but anyway...

1. Sometimes you can set this in your BIOS (either it will ask for a percentage or will allow you to disable smart fan control, which will usually make the fans run at 100% all the time).
2. You can set the fans to go at 100% all the time using ACPI, the way to do that will vary depending on the computer, but you can get some good ideas about how to do it from [here](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/ACPI_fan_control_script) (those are specifically for IBM Thinkpad AFAIK, but it should give you some good ideas on how to perform the same action on your own computer).